# Как получить записи со стены vkontakte?

Tags: vkontakte-api, windowsphone

Как получить записи со стены и отобразить при этом их владельца (фото, фамилия и имя). Приложение для Windows Phone.

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/wall.get